# Response.writeFile code in a popup Not working when invoked from the Callback

Tags: callback

`Response.WriteFile` code in an popup works fine when called from normal `window.open`

If the same popup is been called from an `componentArt` callback the window closes

Note:-
Automatic prompting for downloading file option in tools - internet options -- security - local intranet Zone should be disabled.

Comment: You should specify your programming language as **tag** if you want to get answers, I think most people are filtering for their tags.

Comment: You should also include a code snippet so we can see the problem in context.